# Java Synchronization issue - Main thread locked by the Coroutine implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, libgdx, coroutine

I am working on a game, and I have a problem with thread synchronizations. I have failed miserably to write this properly so main thread does not hang because of this. Short story its creating a locks in my main game thread (game loop). Ill do my best to provide the details, as much as I can. Issue is not related to the game framework, since this is my generic code which is locking everything.

**Background:**

Actions which are occurring in game are executed as Coroutines. Since there is no Coroutine feature in java, they have been implemented as a Coroutines with use of threads. Idea is to have interruptible actions, so when new action is started, execution of the current is paused until new one is finished. This behavior can have more depth as well.

**Question:**

How to properly do synchronization in this case, or how to properly protect my main thread loop ( the update method given in the example) so it does not hangs?

**Here is the simplified use case**. Each action performed ie move units, upgrade whatever completed was executed as a Coroutines or set of Coroutines.

```
Game init:
Player turn: move units around, upgrade stuff and so on
Ai turn:
    Calculate stuff
    Calculate more stuff
    Evaluate player strength
    Evaluate choke points
    More calculations
    Plan attack actions
    Move units>
        Create action (Coroutines) for every single move >
            Coroutine executing for move
                We have to fight in battle between two units
Create action (Coroutines) for every Combat
                        Coroutines executing for Combat
                       Coroutine for combat finished
            Coroutine for move finished
            repeat few times, sometime with and without battle
        Move Coroutine finished
    Move loop finished
Do more stuff
End ai turn;
```

I have been looking at the thread dumps to figure out whats causing this, and its the resume method.

**Thread dumps where you can see the locks**:

**MAIN  Thread Locked** :

```
"LWJGL Application" #18 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000020062800 nid=0x3b20 in Object.wait() [0x0000000022a7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at package_name.Coroutine$CoroutineExecutor.resume(Coroutine.java:319)
        - locked <0x00000006c3aeddd8> (a java.lang.Thread)
        at package_name.Coroutine.resume(Coroutine.java:409)
        at package_name.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:430)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
        at package_name.Game.render(Game.java:273)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:223)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

**OTHER Thread  Locked the MAIN Thread:**

```
"Thread-6" #32 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000020a9e000 nid=0xc94 runnable [0x000000014d64e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        //Doing something here which might take a second or two
        at package_name.Coroutine$CoroutineExecutor$1.run(Coroutine.java:242)
        - locked <0x00000006c3aeddd8> (a java.lang.Thread)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

**Complete Coroutine Code**:

```
package com.game.coroutine;

import com.game.coroutine.CoroutineDeath;
import com.game.coroutine.DeadCoroutineException;
import com.game.coroutine.InternalCoroutineException;
import com.game.coroutine.ResumeSelfCoroutineException;
import com.game.coroutine.YieldOutsideOfCoroutineException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


/**
 * An implementation of Lua-like coroutines.
 * Supports returning values with yield, nesting and it might be thread safe.
 */
public class Coroutine {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Coroutine.class);
    private static List<CoroutineExecutor> executorPool = new ArrayList<>();

    private final Runnable runnable;
    private Object returnValue;
    private boolean finished;

    /** I think CoroutineExecutor is used to map Lua coroutines (not present in Java) to Java Threads.
     * 
     * */
    private static class CoroutineExecutor {

        private boolean running = true;
        private final Thread thread;
        private Coroutine coroutine;

        CoroutineExecutor() {
            thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (thread) {
                        while (running) {
                            try {
                                if (!coroutine.finished) {
                                    coroutine.runnable.run();
                                }
                            } catch (CoroutineDeath | Exception e) {
                                log.error("Error while running coroutine runnable", e);
                            }
                            finally {
                                coroutine.finished = true;
                                coroutine.returnValue = null;
                                thread.notifyAll();
                                try {
                                    thread.wait();
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    log.error("Error while waiting for coroutine runnable", e);
                                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            coroutine = new Coroutine(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() { }
            });
            coroutine.finished = true;
        }

        Object resume() {
            synchronized (thread) {
                if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
                    thread.start();
                }
                thread.notifyAll();
                try {
                    thread.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new InternalCoroutineException("Thread was interrupted while waiting for coroutine to yield.");
                }
                return coroutine.returnValue;
            }
        }

        void yield(Object o) {
            synchronized (thread) {
                coroutine.returnValue = o;
                thread.notifyAll();
                try {
                    thread.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException interrupted) {
                    throw new CoroutineDeath();
                }
            }
        }

        void setCoroutine(Coroutine coroutine) {
            synchronized (thread) {
                if (busy()) {
                    throw new InternalCoroutineException("Coroutine assigned to a busy executor.");
                }
                this.coroutine = coroutine;
            }
        }

        boolean busy() {
            synchronized (Coroutine.class) {
                return !coroutine.finished;
            }
        }

        void reset() {
            synchronized (thread) {
                coroutine.finished = true;
                if (thread.getState() != Thread.State.NEW) {
                    thread.interrupt();
                    try {
                        thread.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        log.error("Error while waiting for coroutine runnable", e);
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        void kill() {
            synchronized (thread) {
                running = false;
                thread.interrupt();
                try {
                    thread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    log.error("Error while waiting for coroutine runnable", e);
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Executor " + thread.getName();
        }
    }

    private Coroutine(Runnable runnable) {
        this.runnable = runnable;
        this.finished = false;
    }


    /**
     * Resumes/starts a coroutine. Return value is the object that the coroutine passed to yield
     */
    public static <T> T resume(Coroutine coroutine) {

        if (coroutine.finished) {
            throw new DeadCoroutineException("An attempt was made to resume a dead coroutine.");
        }

        CoroutineExecutor executor = getExecutorForCoroutine(coroutine);

        if(executor != null) {
            if (executor.equals(getCurrentExecutor())) {
                throw new ResumeSelfCoroutineException("A coroutine cannot resume itself.");
            }
            return (T) executor.resume();
        }
        else {
            log.error("CoroutineExcutor is null");
            return null;
        }
    }


    /**
     * A coroutine can use this to return a value to whatever called resume
     */
    public static void yield(Object o) {

        CoroutineExecutor coroutineExecutor = getCurrentExecutor();
        if (coroutineExecutor != null) {
            Coroutine coroutine = coroutineExecutor.coroutine;

            if (coroutine == null) {
                throw new YieldOutsideOfCoroutineException("Yield cannot be used outside of a coroutine.");
            }

            coroutineExecutor.yield(o);
        } else {
            log.error("CoroutineExcutor is null");
        }

    }


    /**
     * Creates a new coroutine that with the "body" of runnable, doesn't start until resume is used
     */
    public static synchronized  Coroutine create(Runnable runnable) {
        Coroutine coroutine = new Coroutine(runnable);
        CoroutineExecutor coroutineExecutor = getFreeExecutor();
        coroutineExecutor.setCoroutine(coroutine);

        return coroutine;
    }


    /**
     * Stops and cleans up the coroutine
     */
    public static synchronized void destroy(Coroutine coroutine) {
        CoroutineExecutor executor = getExecutorForCoroutine(coroutine);
        if (executor != null) {
            executor.reset();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if resuming this coroutine is possible
     */
    public static synchronized boolean alive(Coroutine coroutine) {
        return coroutine != null && !coroutine.finished;
    }

    /**
     * Shrinks the thread pool
     */
    public static synchronized void cleanup() {
        Iterator<CoroutineExecutor> it = executorPool.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            CoroutineExecutor executor = it.next();
            if (!executor.busy()) {
                executor.kill();
                it.remove();
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current number of executors in the pool
     */
    public static synchronized int poolSize() {
        return executorPool.size();
    }

    private static synchronized CoroutineExecutor getCurrentExecutor() {
        for (CoroutineExecutor e : executorPool) {
            if (Thread.currentThread().equals(e.thread)) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static synchronized CoroutineExecutor getFreeExecutor() {
        for (CoroutineExecutor executor : executorPool) {
            if (!executor.busy()) {
                return executor;
            }
        }
        CoroutineExecutor newExecutor = new CoroutineExecutor();
        executorPool.add(newExecutor);
        return newExecutor;
    }

    private static synchronized CoroutineExecutor getExecutorForCoroutine(Coroutine coroutine) {
        for (CoroutineExecutor executor : executorPool) {
            if (coroutine.equals(executor.coroutine)) {
                return executor;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Finally the **game loop in the main thread** which get stuck because of resume which locked the coroutine thread object:

```
public boolean update() {
    Coroutine coroutine = coroutineQueue.peek();
    if (coroutine != null) {
        if (Coroutine.alive(coroutine)) {
            Event event = Coroutine.resume(coroutine);
            if (event != null) {
                broadcast(event);
            }
        } else {
            coroutineQueue.poll();
        }
    }
    return !coroutineQueue.isEmpty();
}
```

Please Advise on how to correct the synchronisation so at the end of the day, main loop does not get locked and all other Coroutines execute properly, in sequence and pause/continue if required.

Thank you all for taking the time to read this question.
Kind regards

Comment: you may want to give a try with Kotlin, which offers some nice-tuned and fully tested coroutine support

Comment: Unfortunately I cant switch project to Kotlin :(

Comment: libgdx supports Kotlin, you would need to port to Kotlin only the part that is using coroutines, all the rest can remain in Java, no problem

Answer (score 0):

If you do not provide a lock for the `synchronized` keyword, it defaults to using the object. But, in your case, these are all static methods, so it uses the class as the lock. So, all of your coroutines methods are locking on the same thing - the Coroutine class.